# snowflake, how to combine all result into json when doing a group by

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with values like this

table-1

| id | value-1 | value-2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| id-1 | test | `{"id": "value","other": "this"}` |
| id-2 | foo-1 | `{"id": "value","other": "this"}` |
| id-2 | foo-2 | `{"id": "value1","other": "this"}` |

I want to be able to group by column `id` and produce results like

| id | json_value |
| --- | --- |
| id-1 | `[{"value-1": "foo-1","value-2": {"id": "ran","other": "this"}}]` |
| id-2 | `[{"value-1":"foo-1","value-2":{"id":"value1","other":"this"}},{"value-1":"foo-2","value-2":{"id":"value","other":"this"}}]` |

Which is to collect all columns for the grouped id and convert each row to json using column name as key and column value as the actual value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use object_construct and array_agg within group to do this:

```
create or replace temp table T1 as 
select 
COLUMN1::string as id,
COLUMN2::string as "value-1",
COLUMN3::string as "value-2"
from (values
('id-1','test','{"id": "value","other": "this"}'),
('id-2','foo-1','{"id": "value","other": "this"}'),
('id-2','foo-2','{"id": "value1","other": "this"}')
);

select id
      ,array_agg(object_construct('value-1', "value-1", 'value-2', parse_json("value-2")))
       within group (order by ID) as JSON_VALUE
from T1
group by ID
;
```

| ID | JSON_VALUE |
| --- | --- |
| id-1 | [ { "value-1": "test", "value-2": { "id": "value", "other": "this" } } ] |
| id-2 | [ { "value-1": "foo-1", "value-2": { "id": "value", "other": "this" } }, { "value-1": "foo-2", "value-2": { "id": "value1", "other": "this" } } ] |

Comment: Thank you, yes i was thinking the same. I am looking for option on how to see i can generate this without explicitly name each column